# c++ debugger stops in wrong place on crash, VS10 win7

Tags: c++, debugging, callstack

This is a small program i wrote to reproduce the error i get:

```
#include <assert.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int* nPtr = 0;
    *nPtr = 5;

    //assert(0 && "testing");

    //static int nZero = 0;
    //static float x = 5 / nZero;

    return 0;
}
```

the call stack is wrong, and there is now way to retrace the error.
im compiling with no optimization in 32 bit.
the pdb matches the exe.

this is the call stack i get:

```
ntdll.dll!76f615de()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!76f615de()    
ntdll.dll!76f5014e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_unlock(int locknum)  Line 375    C
003df930()  
cccccccc()
```

thanks alot,
Evgeny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i was looking for in [here](http://www.os2museum.com/wp/avx-support-disrupts-wow64-debugging/)

in short, the AVX causes an error in the call stack after exceptions.

you can tern AVX off by:

```
bcdedit /set xsavedisable 1
```

restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken.
 Your pointer doesn't point to a valid `int` when you write through it. That's undefined behaviour and your compiler may generate whatever it wants. 
That the stacktrace in the debugger doesn't make sense is irrelevant since there is no way to know what to expect - such is the nature of *undefined* behavior.

Comment: Well, the debugger can only show you the call stack that the compiler actually generated (assuming it is even valid since the stack could be corrupt). Since the code has undefined behaviour the compiler is free to generate nonsense and how would the debugger be able to help you then? Except by showing you what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Int *p ＝0 
,which means that p points 0x00000000，it is not accessable。so you change the *p，it will cause pession denied

Comment: No. That's not guaranteed. It is undefined behaviour (since `p` is `nullptr`) and *anything* could happen - no diagnostic or runtime error required. The compiler may generate whatever it pleases (or nothing at all).